# Copy S3 Object with MultiPartUpload

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-s3

I need to rename a quite a bunch of objects in AWS S3. For small objects the following snippet works flawlessly:

```
input := &s3.CopyObjectInput{
    Bucket:     aws.String(bucket),
    Key:        aws.String(targetPrefix),
    CopySource: aws.String(source),
}
_, err = svc.CopyObject(input)
if err != nil {
    panic(errors.Wrap(err, "error copying object"))
}
```

I am running into the S3 size limitation for larger objects. I understand I need to copy the object using a multi part upload. This is what I tried so far:

```
multiPartUpload, err := svc.CreateMultipartUpload(
    &s3.CreateMultipartUploadInput{
        Bucket: aws.String(bucket),
        Key: aws.String(targetPrefix), // targetPrefix is the new name
    },
)
if err != nil {
    panic(errors.Wrap(err, "could not create MultiPartUpload"))
}
resp, err := svc.UploadPartCopy(
    &s3.UploadPartCopyInput{
        UploadId:   multiPartUpload.UploadId,
        Bucket:     aws.String(bucket),
        Key:        aws.String(targetPrefix),
        CopySource: aws.String(source),
        PartNumber: aws.Int64(1),
    },
)
if err != nil {
    panic(errors.Wrap(err, "error copying multipart object"))
}
log.Printf("copied: %v", resp)
```

The golang SDK bails out on me with:

```
InvalidRequest: The specified copy source is larger than the maximum allowable size for a copy source: 5368709120
```

I have also tried the following approach but I do not get any parts listed here:

```
multiPartUpload, err := svc.CreateMultipartUpload(
    &s3.CreateMultipartUploadInput{
        Bucket: aws.String(bucket),
        Key: aws.String(targetPrefix), // targetPrefix is the new name
    },
)
if err != nil {
    panic(errors.Wrap(err, "could not create MultiPartUpload"))
}
err = svc.ListPartsPages(
    &s3.ListPartsInput{
        Bucket:   aws.String(bucket),       // Required
        Key:      obj.Key,                  // Required
        UploadId: multiPartUpload.UploadId, // Required
    },
    // Iterate over all parts in the `CopySource` object
    func(parts *s3.ListPartsOutput, lastPage bool) bool {
        log.Printf("parts:\n%v\n%v", parts, parts.Parts)
        // parts.Parts is an empty slice
        for _, part := range parts.Parts {
            log.Printf("copying %v part %v", source, part.PartNumber)
            resp, err := svc.UploadPartCopy(
                &s3.UploadPartCopyInput{
                    UploadId:   multiPartUpload.UploadId,
                    Bucket:     aws.String(bucket),
                    Key:        aws.String(targetPrefix),
                    CopySource: aws.String(source),
                    PartNumber: part.PartNumber,
                },
            )
            if err != nil {
                panic(errors.Wrap(err, "error copying object"))
            }
            log.Printf("copied: %v", resp)
        }
        return true
    },
)
if err != nil {
    panic(errors.Wrap(err, "something went wrong with ListPartsPages!"))
}
```

What am I doing wrong or am I missunderstanding something?

Answer (score 2):

I think that `ListPartsPages` is the wrong direction because it works on "Multipart Uploads" which is a different entity than an an s3 "Object". So you're listing the already-uploaded parts to the multipart upload you just created.

Your first example is close to what's needed, but you need to manually split the original file into parts, with the range of each part specified by `UploadPartCopyInput`'s `CopySourceRange`. At least that's my take from reading the documentation.

Comment: Are you saying I need to manually loop and calculate the values for `CopySourceRange` in the `UploadPartCopyInput`? That seems doable but ... cumbersome :(

Comment: Also, am I ethically required to upvote and accept if that is correct but I really really dislike how the AWS guys implemented this SDK? ;)

Comment: I'm saying that I think it'd work if you manually looped, and that a cursory reading of the api endpoints don't offer any obvious alternatives. It's kind of surprising that they don't have anything that abstracts away the details in the client library though. Should definitely be added to `s3/s3manager`...

Comment: oh the pain. 3 years later and I run into the same bug and end up at this question...